# Handling JavaScript load sequence in Kotlin

Tags: javascript, html, kotlin, dom

I'm using Kotlin to write a JavaScript application, but I immediately ran into the problem of how JS executes. i.e. I tried to call `document.getElementById()` before the whole page loaded, resulting in errors as Kotlin could not cast a DOM object that doesn't exist yet.

The way around this I found was to use the `window.onLoad()` function, but this didn't feel right to me- Sticking all of the program's logic inside `onLoad(`) seems like a hack.

Is there a better way of handling things like this via Kotlin? Or was I right to use onLoad() for running main? This is my first time using Kotlin to write JS so any extra advice and tips would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that the code you are calling is contained in the body of your html above the scripts.

```html
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Console Output</title>
</head>
<body>
<div>
my html content up here!
</div>
<script language="JavaScript" type="application/javascript" src="target/js/lib/kotlin.js"></script>
<script language="JavaScript" type="application/javascript" src="target/js/my-program.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```